# Returning a partial nested document in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to search an array of nested documents and return only those that fit a specific criteria.

An example mapping would be:

```
{"book":
    {"properties":
        {
         "title":{"type":"string"},
         "chapters":{
                     "type":"nested",
                     "properties":{"title":{"type":"string"},
                                   "length":{"type":"long"}}
                                  }
                     }
          }
     }
}
```

So, say I want to look for chapters titled "epilogue". 
Not all the books have such a chapter, but If I use a nested query I'd get, as a result, all the chapters in a book that *has* such a chapter. While all I'm interested is the chapters themselves that have such a title.

I'm mainly concerned about i/o and net traffic since there might be a lot of chapters.

Also, is there a way of retrieving ONLY the nested document, without the containing doc?

Comment: Aren't chapters always nested under the books object?

Comment: You can't with nested docs afaik. You could however remodel this to a parent (book)-child(chapter) relationship . In that case your problem + answer is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431889/how-can-i-retrieve-matching-children-only

Comment: relevant issues on github to make it possible to return a matching nested-context: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1383 and the newer https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3022

Comment: @Geert-Jan parent-child is not good enough, since it does the join in-memory, and my DB is huge (several hundreds of GBs...). Thanks for the tip, though :)

Comment: Parent child improved a lot with 0.90. Maybe you can try it out. Otherwise it's not possible to do what you want in a single query.

Comment: @javanna, how about several queries? the first can return, for example, just the ID of the parent (book), can I do it with several queries?

Comment: Yes if you index them in different documents. You would be doing parent child manually.

Comment: Oh. I meant if it's still nested. Alright then, I guess that's a no. 'Thanks anyway!

Comment: Problem is that even though nested documents are currently indexed as separate documents internally, you cannot get back from elasticsearch only those separate documents by now.

Comment: It looks like it will finally be possible to do this on elasticsearch 1.5: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2662

Answer (score 13):

This is a very old question I stumbled upon, so I'll show two different approaches to how this can be handled.

Let's prepare index and some test data first:

```
PUT /bookindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "book": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "chapters": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "title": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "length": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /bookindex/book/1
{
  "title": "My first book ever",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "title": "epilogue",
      "length": 1230
    },
    {
      "title": "intro",
      "length": 200
    }
  ]
}

PUT /bookindex/book/2
{
  "title": "Book of life",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "title": "epilogue",
      "length": 17
    },
    {
      "title": "toc",
      "length": 42
    }
  ]
}
```

Now that we have this data in Elasticsearch, we can retrieve just the relevant hits using an [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html). This approach is very straightforward, but I prefer the approach outlined at the end.

```
# Inner hits query
POST /bookindex/book/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "chapters",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "chapters.title": "epilogue"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The `inner_hits` nested query returns documents, where each hit contains an `inner_hits` object with all of the matching documents, including scoring information. You can see the [response](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04de9d3e4b8c29bbdde29887f8b07f2b).

My preferred approach to this type of query is using a [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) with [filtered](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) sub aggregation which contains `top_hits` sub aggregation. The query looks like:

```
# Nested and filter aggregation
POST /bookindex/book/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "chapters"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter": {
          "filter": {
            "match": { "chapters.title": "epilogue" }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "t": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `top_hits` sub aggregation is the one doing the actual retrieving
of nested documents and supports `from` and `size` properties among
others. From the documentation:

> If the `top_hits` aggregator is wrapped in a `nested` or `reverse_nested`
>   aggregator then nested hits are being returned. Nested hits are in a
>   sense hidden mini documents that are part of regular document where in
>   the mapping a nested field type has been configured. The `top_hits`
>   aggregator has the ability to un-hide these documents if it is wrapped
>   in a `nested` or `reverse_nested` aggregator. Read more about nested in
>   the nested type mapping.

The [response from Elasticsearch](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d2e78520dcbaacdca224a455a9a3311) is (IMO) prettier (and it seems to return it faster (though this is not a scientific observation)) and "easier" to parse.