# ElasticSearch : search and return nested type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty new to ElasticSearch and I am having trouble using nested mapping / query.

I have the following data structure added to my index :

```
{
   "_id": "3",
   "_rev": "6-e9e1bc15b39e333bb4186de05ec1b167",
   "skuCode": "test",
   "name": "Dragon vol. 1",
   "pages": [
       {
           "id": "1", 
           "tags": [
               {
                   "name": "dragon"
               },
               {
                   "name": "japonese"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": "2",               
           "tags": [
               {
                   "name": "tagforanotherpage"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

This index mapping is defined as bellow :

```
{
  "metabook" : {
    "metabook" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_rev" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "pages" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "tags" : {
              "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "skuCode" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to search all pages containing a specific tag, and return the book object with the filtered page list (I would like ES to return only pages that match the given tag). Something like (ignoring the second page) :

```
{
   "_id": "3",
   "_rev": "6-e9e1bc15b39e333bb4186de05ec1b167",
   "skuCode": "test",
   "name": "Dragon vol. 1",
   "pages": [
       {
           "id": "1",               
           "tags": [
               {
                   "name": "dragon"
               },
               {
                   "name": "japonese"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Here is the query I actually use :

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 10,
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "pages",
        "score_mode" : "avg",
        "query" : {
           "term" : { "tags.name" : "japonese" }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

But it actually returns an empty result. What am I doing wrong ? Maybe I should index my "pages" directly instead of books ? What am I missing ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't get back only parts of the a document. If the document matches a query, you will get the whole thing back; the root and all nested docs. If you want to get only parts back, then you could look at using parent/child docs.

Also you aren't seeing any hits as you have a small syntax error in the nested query. Look closely at the field name:

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 10,
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "pages",
        "score_mode" : "avg",
        "query" : {
           "term" : { "pages.tags.name" : "japonese" }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need help with parent child docs feel free to ask! (There should be examples if you do a google search)

Good luck!

Comment: I think they have something in the pipeline to do what you're asking, but not released yet...

Comment: It did not work for me I use following query:{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "language",
      "score_mode": "avg",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "language.langName": "English"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: The feature you are looking for is `inner_hits` which seems to got added in version 1.5, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788553/returning-a-partial-nested-document-in-elasticsearch?noredirect=1&lq=1